# How can I call 2 different URLs with 2 inputs using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

How can I do short JS coding that ? I would like to write value and data-sutun's result with a Ajax.

```
<input autocomplete="off"
       data-sutun="namedata"
       type="text"
       id="form-name"
       name="gonkod"
       class="form-control input-data typeahead" />

<input autocomplete="off"
       data-sutun="countrydata"
       type="text"
       id="form-country"
       name="gonkod"
       class="form-control input-data typeaheadtwo" />
```

---

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
      var verim = $('#form-name').data('sutun');

      return $.post("{{ URL }}{{ dil }}/ajax/autogkod", { query: query, verim :verim }, function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        return process(data);
      });
    },
    showHintOnFocus:'all'
  });
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input.typeaheatow').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
      var verim = $('#form-country').data('sutun');

      return $.post("{{ URL }}{{ dil }}/ajax/autogkod", { query: query, verim :verim }, function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        return process(data);
      });
    },
    showHintOnFocus:'all'
  });
});
```

Comment: First thing you can do is to only have one document ready function.... no need to declare multiple....  second, put your AJAX call into a fuction that accepts some arguments (the input selector, for example).....

Comment: @cale_b: the ajax is part of a plugin instantiation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you need to pass element specific data to individual instances of a plugin use an `each` loop so you can access the element instance inside `each` as `this`

```
$('#form-name, #form-country').each(function(){
   var $input = $(this),
        // store verim here since `this` might be different in source callback
        verim = $input.data('sutun');

   $input.typeahead({
       .....

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could do it

Answer (score 0):

If the `{{ URL }}` is different for the two inputs...

Have the `{{ URL }}` in a data attribute for each.

```
<input autocomplete="off"
       data-sutun="namedata"
       data-url="{{ URL }}{{ dil }}/ajax/autogkod"
       type="text"
       id="form-name"
       name="gonkod"
       class="form-control input-data typeahead" />

<input autocomplete="off"
       data-sutun="countrydata"
       data-url="{{ URL }}{{ dil }}/ajax/autogkod"
       type="text"
       id="form-country"
       name="gonkod"
       class="form-control input-data typeaheadtwo" />
```

Then, in the [`typeahead`](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) instantiation, use `$(this).data("url")`.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input.typeahead, input.typeaheadtwo').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
      var verim = $('#form-name').data('sutun');

      return $.post($(this).data("url"), { query: query, verim :verim }, function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        return process(data);
      });
    },
    showHintOnFocus:'all'
  });
});
```

Notice that you can have more than one selector... You can coma separate them like this: `$('input.typeahead, input.typeaheatwo')`